# Анимация на форме во время загрузки

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Есть некий процесс, во время которого мне  нужно показывать форму. На этой форме лежит компонент из Devexpress - ProgressPanel. Этот компонент отображает определённую анимацию. Проблема в том, что никак не получается отобразить эту форму так, чтобы анимация отображалась - она фризится на первом кадре. Просьба подсказать, как сделать так чтобы не фризилась. Пробовал использовать backgroundworker - тоже фризится

```
fWaiting form;
private void bUserDataRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    form = new fWaiting();
    form.TopMost = true;
    form.Show();
    Application.DoEvents();

    //fmain.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
    //{
    //    form = new fWaiting();
    //    form.TopMost = true;
    //    form.Show();
    //    Application.DoEvents();
    //}));
    Classes.MySQL.UpdateUser(userdata);
    form.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Успешно","",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил использованием DevExpress компонента **splashScreenManager**